How to Upgrade the Jprofiler 12 existing key to Jprofiler 13/14 for Kubectl features and other new features?
I have existing key for Jporfiler 12 with my Company and i want to use the same key for Jprofiler 13/14 versions and take benifit of new features provided Jprofiler.
help on how to migrate existing key to newer versions of Jprofler

You need to purchase an upgrade at https://www.ej-technologies.com/buy/jprofiler/select?target=upgrade

thank you reply, i have checked on this but it seems jprofiler12 key is not eligible for it.

You can purchase an upgrade for all previous versions. The check on the website if you are eligible for an upgrade is for the free upgrade only.
